The react native app shows an error when we've implemented the sign in & sign out
So we was linking the existing aws amplify back-end in the cloud which is the authentication part to the react native (Enable sign-up, sign-in, and sign-out, https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/react-native/build-a-backend/auth/enable-sign-up/) and all the steps of the sign in and sign out has been done but the app then shows this error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined, js engine: hermes
ERROR Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
ERROR Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
I've tried to fix this issue by digging deep into the error using various tools but nothing helped me and I keep getting the same error so it requires someone who is more experienced in react native back-end.
